# How to call onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) just on longPress in ListView?

Tags: java, android

I am using SwipeList library to implement list in my activity.

```
myList=(SwipeListView)findViewById(R.id.my_swipe_lv_list);
```

In method`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` I used to register list for context menu

```
registerForContextMenu(callogList);
```

Also I override 
`public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)`
and

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) .
```

I have problem when I click on item in list ContexMenu is shown, I want to call contextMenu just on longPress it's supposed to be the default behavior.

Any help ???